# Trying to Sync weekdays between 2 years

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to come up with something to Sync weekdays between years

So far I can do it for a 4 year gap just by subtracting 364 days

For example
Monday Feb 1 2021 - 364 days becomes Monday Feb 3rd 2020
Friday Feb 19 2021 - 364 days becomes Friday Feb 21nd 2020
Tuesday Mar 2 2021 - 364 days becomes Tuesday Mar 3rd 2020

notice how the weekday is in perfect sync (Monday to Monday, Tuesday to Tuesday etc)

and I can do this for 2 years just by using 728 days (364 * 2)
and so on for 3 and 4 years

my problem is after 4 years it stops working

if I do the same thing for 5 Years (364*5)

Monday Feb 1st 2021 becomes Monday Feb 8th 2016
however I would want it to be Monday Feb 1st 2016

I cant seem to crack how to deal with this for 5 years on

Comment: Look into leap years. Every year that is a multiple of 4 is a leap year, except when it is a multiple of 100 that is not a multiple of 400. A leap year has a 29th of February.

Answer (score 0):

This is using [Zeller’s Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) to get the day number, and then just modifying the actual date when subtracting 365 days to get the day name to match.  I'm sure there are edge cases (e.g. I believe this would currently allow a result of something like "March 33"), but this should get you started:

```js
const days = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];

const dayNum = (day, month, year) => {
    if (month <= 2) {
        year--;
        month += 12;
    }
    month-=2;
    const lastTwoDigitsOfYear = year % 100;
    const firstTwoDigitsOfYear = (year - lastTwoDigitsOfYear) / 100
    let F = day + Math.floor((13*month-1)/5) + lastTwoDigitsOfYear + Math.floor(lastTwoDigitsOfYear/4) +Math.floor(firstTwoDigitsOfYear/4)-2*firstTwoDigitsOfYear
    let f = F >= 0 ? (F % 7) : 7 + (F % 7);
    return f
}

// Ok, so we can get the day for any date.

const syncedYearAdd = (day, month, year, numYears) => {
    const d1 = dayNum(day, month, year);
    const d2 = dayNum(day, month, year + numYears);
    if (d1 < d2) {
        day -= (d2 - d1)
    } else if (d1 > d2) {
        day += (d1 - d2);
    }
    if (day < 0) {
        day += 7;
    }
    console.log(days[d1], day, months[month-1], year + numYears)
}

// Monday Feb 1st 2021
for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    syncedYearAdd(1, 2, 2021, i * -1)
}
```